# NumberFormatException while trying to parser string to an int

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, text-files

This is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class CreateMatrix {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("score.txt"));
        String line = null;

        int[][] array = new int[3][2];
        int lineCount = 0;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          String[] parts = line.split("[(),]");
          for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                array[lineCount][i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
            }
        }
        br.close();
      }
    }
```

input:

```
(2,1)
(9,7)
(9,8)
```

and I'm getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)<br>
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)<br>
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)<br>
    at CreateMatrix.main(CreateMatrix.java:15)<br>
```

can anyone tell me which part I did wrong?

I modified my code and they are working fine now:

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.FileReader;

 public class CreateMatrix {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("score.txt"));
        String line = null;

        int[][] array = new int[3][2];
        int lineCount = 0;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
              line = line.substring(line.indexOf('(')+1, line.lastIndexOf(')'));
              String[] parts = line.split(",");
              for (int i = 0; i<parts.length; i++) {
                array[lineCount][i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
                //System.out.println("{" + array[lineCount][i] + "}");
              }
              lineCount++;
            }
        br.close();
        System.out.println("{" + array[0][1] + "}");
        System.out.println("{" + array[1][1] + "}");
      }
    }
```

but if I want to store  1,7,8 to 2D array and 2,9,9 to 1D array how can I do that?

```
val01 [] ={2,9} 
val02 [0][0] = {1}
val02 [1][0] = {7,8}
```

Comment: print out parts[] after you retrieve them.  You probably have some empty strings.  Eg. on input (123), you may get "", "123", "".  Skip them.

Comment: got an empty space on load, do if (!parts[i].equals("")) array[line...

Comment: your have empty element in array http://ideone.com/PhnnK9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is because the split logic is not correct. Your split logic is generating three parts, `""`, `"2"`, `"1"`, that is why you are getting the exception.

You can simply debug this, by printing the `length` and `content` of the split `String` array. (comment the `parseInt` statement just to get the complete output.)

---

First remove the `(` and `)` from the input and then simply split by `,`.

```
  line = line.substring(line.indexOf('(')+1, line.lastIndexOf(')'));
  String[] parts = line.split(",");
```

Use the above code. to replace the your split logic.

You should also increment the `lineCount`, other it will just simply overwrite the data in the first row. The initial value is zero (0), which is not updated anytime in the loop.

---

Here is the correct while-loop:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  line = line.substring(line.indexOf('(')+1, line.lastIndexOf(')'));
  String[] parts = line.split(",");
  for (int i = 0; i<parts.length; i++) {
    array[lineCount][i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
  }
  lineCount++;
}
```

Comment: Not the down voter but i think the OP is already splitting on ( ) and , so no need to replace ! Also the error is because the string is empty.

Comment: Because the OP logic is getting an extra space in the start. When the line is split by `(`.

Comment: Thank you for the help@YoungHobbit. Can you help me again, I put the details above

Answer (score 0):

You have got everything right all what you need to do is make sure that the string is not null or empty before trying to parse it to an int.

```
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
     // Add these lines 
     if(parts[i]==null || parts[i].trim().isEmpty()) { 
          continue;
     }
     // till here
     array[lineCount][i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
}
```

This happens because when you split on () or , for (2,1) you get 3 parts.

```
parts[0] = ""
parts[1] = "2"
parts[2] = "1"
```

As you see first part is blank.

Comment: The length is coming as 3 not 4.

Comment: Yes. I have printed it.